# Pure jquery method for wrapping each 9 img's in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which contains a certain number of img's. Let's say 21. What I want to do is wrap a div around every 9 img's. In what way can I achieve this?

My html structure:

```
<div id="parent">
   <img src="#">
   <img src="#">
   <img src="#">
   <img src="#">
   <img src="#">
   <img src="#">
   <img src="#">
   <img src="#">
   <img src="#">
   <img src="#">
   <img src="#">
   <img src="#">
   <img src="#">
   <img src="#">
   <img src="#">
</div>
```

Which should become:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div>
      <img src="#">
      <img src="#">
      <img src="#">
      <img src="#">
      <img src="#">
      <img src="#">
      <img src="#">
      <img src="#">
      <img src="#">
   </div>
   <div>
      <img src="#">
      <img src="#">
      <img src="#">
      <img src="#">
      <img src="#">
      <img src="#">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: << What I want to do is wrap a div around every 9 img's.>> is quite ambigous. Hopefully you have added a sample of what you want to achieve

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var $img = $("#parent img");
for (var i = 0; i < $img.length; i += 9) {
    $img.slice(i, i + 9).wrapAll("<div/>");
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/svgu4/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not pure jQuery but works:http://jsfiddle.net/GEQyA/

html:

```
<div id="parent">

<img src="" class="image"/>
<img src="" class="image"/>
<img src="" class="image"/>
<img src="" class="image"/>
<img src="" class="image"/>
<img src="" class="image"/>
```

js:

```
var $images = [];
$('#parent').children().each(function(index, value){
$images.push(this);
});
$('#parent').children().each(function(index, value){
$(this).remove();
});

$('#parent').ready(function(){
write();
});

function write() {
var counter = 0;

$('#parent').append('<div class="innerDiv">');
$($images).each(function(index, value){
    if (counter == 2) {
        $('#parent').append('</div><div class="innerDiv">');
        counter = 0;
    }

    $('#parent').append($(this) + counter);

    if (index == $images.length) {
        $('#parent').append('</div>');
    }
    counter += 1;
});
}
```